# Make all anchor tags stop html5 audio players

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

Ok I'm stumped.  I've tried a few things to make this work without success.  Again, I'm a beginner so I've probably overlooked something.

On my page, I have various html5 `<audio>` players.  I want to make it so when a user clicks any anchor tag (link) on the page, any and/or all of the audio players that are currently playing, pause their audio.  How can I accomplish this with jquery?

Thank you in advance for any support!

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio/Friedman_Doku.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="audio/wav/Friedman_Doku.wav" type="audio/wav">Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: show us your audio.play() function call

Comment: not too sure what you mean.  I'm using html5 with the `<audio controls><source="myaudio.wav"></audio>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("DOM Ready");
$('a').click(function(){
     $('audio').each(function() {
     if(!this.paused){
        this.pause();
     }
    });
});
});
```

This will make it so that when you click any a tag on the page, all audio tags will stop, hope it helps.

Comment: So you don't want it to play when the a tag is clicked again? Then just remove the replay part so it will just be... 

    $('a').click(function() { 
        $('audio').each(function() { 
            var sound = $(this);
            sound.pause();
        });
    });

Comment: Have you made sure you have the JQuery plugin at the top of the page?

Comment: the jquery plugin is there.  I have been using scroll easing as well as bootstrap components.  Jquery is working.  My website is basically just one page.  All anchor tags point to #ids.  I want to make it so when an anchor is clicked any audio that is currently playing is paused.

Comment: look how the audio html5 markup is written. could be wrong. so the question is, does it play sound first?

Comment: I'll copy a markup straight from my site.  `<audio controls>
         <source src="audio/Friedman_Doku.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
         <source src="audio/wav/Friedman_Doku.wav" type="audio/wav">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
       </audio>`

Comment: the audio elements on my site work perfectly fine.  I've tested them on multiple browsers.

Comment: If that is the case then the code that @codelio edited on my post should be perfectly fine, try that and see if the DOM is actually ready at that point... if not then it will be because it's not getting to the point of the JQuery even loading, if you don't know then to check the DOM in google chrome press f12 and go to the console tab, try refreshing if you still see nothing then JQuery isn't loading

Comment: Yep that code now works.  Thank you guys alot.  I've learned something today haha!

Comment: Awesome, you've very much welcome. If you need any more help with anything, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: actually I do have a small question.  I've appended the script above to include `'audio'` as well as `'a'`.  The only problem now is the current player won't pause its audio if its playing.  I either need to click a link or another play for it to pause.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: The script above, I've added: `$('a, audio').click(function(){
     $('audio').each(function() {
     if(!this.paused){
        this.pause();
     }
    });
});
});`

Comment: This makes it so clicking another audio player pauses an already playing one.  The only problem now is the current playing player won't pause when clicking the pause button on that player.

Comment: well then unfold your function to have back control over the elements separated.

Comment: sorry codelio, but you're going to have to show me.  Again, I'm pretty much a beginner and taking on a bit more than I can chew I guess :)

Comment: That's because in your first definition of: $('a, audio').click you've told it to perform the function whenever you click an anchor tag or an audio tag